# Unable to deploy EJB on weblogic server

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts-1, ejb-2.x

I have a web application(Java EE, Struts 1.1, JSP, Tomcat 5.5.20, WebLogic, Oracle) running on a Linux sever from Red Hat.
I edit a table and add  some fields on it(database).Then I edit the reqiured files in Jbuilder7 .clean and make the related jar file and the last,clean  and make the ear file.the earfile is made without errors.But when I deploy earfile on weblogic server,the errors have occured as the followings**(Unable to deploy EJB: markaz.jar from markaz.jar).**
Please guide me!what should I do?

```
at weblogic.ejb20.ejbc.EJBCompiler.doCompile(EJBCompi ler.java:249)
at weblogic.ejb20.ejbc.EJBCompiler.compileEJB(EJBComp iler.java:344)
at weblogic.ejb20.deployer.EJBDeployer.runEJBC(EJBDep loyer.java:489)
at weblogic.ejb20.deployer.EJBDeployer.compileEJB(EJB Deployer.java:819)
at weblogic.ejb20.deployer.EJBDeployer.prepare(EJBDep loyer.java:1268)
at weblogic.ejb20.deployer.EJBModule.prepare(EJBModul e.java:232)
at weblogic.j2ee.J2EEApplicationContainer.prepareModu le(J2EEApplicationContainer.java:1570)
at weblogic.j2ee.J2EEApplicationContainer.prepare(J2E EApplicationContainer.java:737)
at weblogic.j2ee.J2EEApplicationContainer.prepare(J2E EApplicationContainer.java:555)
at weblogic.j2ee.J2EEApplicationContainer.prepare(J2E EApplicationContainer.java:458)
at weblogic.management.deploy.slave.SlaveDeployer.pre pareAllStagedApplications(SlaveDeployer.java:490)
at weblogic.management.deploy.slave.SlaveDeployer.ini tialize(SlaveDeployer.java:253)
at weblogic.management.deploy.DeploymentManagerServer LifeCycleImpl.initialize(DeploymentManagerServerLi feCycleImpl.java:150)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerLifeCycleList.initialize(Se rverLifeCycleList.java:54)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.initialize1(T3Srvr.java:78 2)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.initialize(T3Srvr.java:594 )
at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:282)
at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:32)

}.
weblogic.management.ApplicationException: Prepare failed. Task Id = null
{
Module Name: markaz.jar, Error: Exception preparing module: EJBModule(markaz.jar,status=NEW)
```

Unable to deploy EJB: markaz.jar from markaz.jar

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late , but i stumbled here googling for a solution for the same problem.
In my case the issue was because the compiled version of the ear was not compatible with the weblogic version.
I built the application on JDK 1.6 and was trying to deploy it on weblogic 8.1 , and was getting similar error.
I re-built it using JDK 1.4 and redeployed and it worked.
Also have a look at this link -->
http://objectmix.com/weblogic/519082-wl-8-1-deployment-error-class-bytes-found-but-defineclass-failed.html

Hope that helps.